# Why do I get child_added event on remove?

Tags: firebase

The following code produces an endless loop of repeated child_added, though I never add a child. The nodes are removed. I just loop forever. How can I fix this?

```
//notifications branch is pre-populated when I get here:
notifications.startAt(null).on('child_added', processNotification, logError);

function processNotification(notification)
{
    removeNotification(notification);
}

function removeNotification(notification)
{
    var child = notifications.child(notification.name());
    console.log("REMOVING", child.toString());
    child.remove();     
}
```

What I log is the same four nodes (A,B,C,D) being removed:

```
REMOVING https://my.firebaseio.com/experimental/-JVMi0_4poXfOWUt5g49 - A
REMOVING https://my.firebaseio.com/experimental/-JVMi1Y_bFwZAkffRel4 - B
REMOVING https://my.firebaseio.com/experimental/-JVMi2lyhKj8z27ik71x - C
REMOVING https://my.firebaseio.com/experimental/-JVMhzazdgHYAstqxu8L - D
REMOVING https://my.firebaseio.com/experimental/-JVMi0_4poXfOWUt5g49 - A
REMOVING https://my.firebaseio.com/experimental/-JVMi1Y_bFwZAkffRel4 - B
REMOVING https://my.firebaseio.com/experimental/-JVMi2lyhKj8z27ik71x - C
REMOVING https://mu.firebaseio.com/experimental/-JVMhzazdgHYAstqxu8L - D
...
```

Comment: Does this also happen when you replace `var child = notifications.child(notification.name());` with `var child = notification.ref();`

Comment: Well, the issue is the call back not the reference. The remove happens. I'm not seeing how that would matter if it works. What's your thinking?

Comment: My reasoning is that it looks convoluted and I didn't have time to reproduce the problem. Alternatively you might also want to look at https://github.com/firebase/firebase-work-queue, which does something akin to what you're trying. They use a `transaction` handler that returns `null` to remove the handled items there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultimately, I just dropped the query and went with normal processing, dropping the "startAt(null)":

```
notifications.on('child_added', processNotification, logError);
```

It's not obvious that the behavior will be different from the documentation, but the startAt(null) does not produce the same behavior (though in thoery it should). I would love to see this better documented.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to reproduce the problem. I think it is caused by the fact that the `Query` tries to keep items in its "window" when you remove one.

You can work around this problem by using a `once('value'` instead of `on('child_added'`, like this:

```
notifications.startAt(null).once('value', processNotifications);

function processNotifications(notifications)
{
    notifications.forEach(function(notification) {
        notification.ref().remove();
    });
}
```

Since the `value` only fires `once`, it will not be interfering with the `remove` operation.

Comment: I was also able to fix it by just droppng the query all together:

Comment: That is my preferred way of working. Queries seem powerful, but they are sometimes contra-intuitive. Can you post an answer with your solution and accept that? That way others know how you solved it.